# Phonegap Database Call Too Slow

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova

I have developed a Phonegap Application that shows me all the rows of a table. This table has about 9,000 rows, and the iteration of all these elements is really slow. It takes about 20 seconds to get it.

This is part of the code:

```
function getProducts(){
        var query ="SELECT name FROM table";

        db.transaction(function (tx){
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results){
                var len = results.rows.length;

                if(len == 0 ){
                    hideWaitingMessage();
                    $('#elementList').empty();
                    $('#elementList').append("<li data-theme='e'><h3>No items</h3></li>");
                }else{
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                        $("#elementList").append("<li><a onClick='goToProduct()'><h3>" + results.rows.item(i).name+ "</h3></a></li>");
                    }
                    hideWaitingMessage();
                }

                $('#elementList').listview('refresh');              

            }, callBack);
        }, callBack);
    }

Very simple, it works, but toooooo slow. Any suggestion to speed it up?
```

Comment: And those 9000 rows are all shown on the phone screen at the same time?

Comment: yes, its a list of products and I generate the HTML in running time, a list and each <li> is one of the rows

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile takes more time for refreshing list view so better you use a simple list with user defined  style -it will load in better time

Comment: Do I need to take out the jquery mobile css and js reference in the HTML to do that? I already use a css class written for me, but I don't know if that's what it takes not to use jquery mobile